# split the file into multiple files based on a string in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text file with the below data having no particular format

```
abc*123     *180109*1005*^*001*0000001*0*T*:~
efg*05*1*X*005010X2A1~
k7*IT 1234*P*234df~ 
hig*0109*10052200*Rq~
abc*234*9698*709870*99999*N:~
tng****MI*917937861~
k7*IT 8876*e*278df~
dtp*D8*20171015~
```

I want the output as two files as below :

Based on string `abc`, I want to split the file.

file 1:

```
abc*123     *180109*1005*^*001*0000001*0*T*:~
efg*05*1*X*005010X2A1~
k7*IT 1234*P*234df~ 
hig*0109*10052200*Rq~
```

file 2:

```
abc*234*9698*709870*99999*N:~
tng****MI*917937861~
k7*IT 8876*e*278df~
dtp*D8*20171015~
```

And the file names should be IT name(the line starts with k7) so file1 name should be IT_1234 second file name should be IT_8876.

Comment: Which amount of data would there be in each new file?

Comment: Why do you want to do this with Spark? Why not, say, bash? Is the file on HDFS?

Comment: Yes, could you give us an idea of the end goal of doing so; would help us finding the appropriate solution.

Comment: Yes ,Per each hour we are getting 2.5 GB of data and the file is in HDFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this little dirty trick that I used for a project :

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "abc")
```

You can set the delimiter of your spark context for reading files. So you could do something like this :

```
val delimit = "abc"
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", delimit)
val df = sc.textFile("your_original_file.txt")
           .map(x => (delimit ++ x))
           .toDF("delimit_column")
           .filter(col("delimit_column") !== delimit)
```

Then you can map each element of your DataFrame (or RDD) to be written to a file.

It's a dirty method but it might help you !

Have a good day

PS : The filter at the end is to drop the first line which is empty with the concatenated delimiter

Comment: Thank you. I can use this solution. I have edited the question ,Please help me with that

Comment: Hello, I don't think you can name files in Spark. You should either use the hadoop library and create the paths with filenames before writing. Or create a shell script

Comment: Hi , What if I have the "abc" string in the middle of the record ,in this case instead of 2 I will get 3 records in the output .Can we use substring functions here when defining the delimit

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit from *sparkContext's* `wholeTextFiles` function to read the file. Then *parse* it to separate the strings ( here I have used `####` as distinct combination of characters that won't repeat in the text)

```
val rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("path to the file")
  .flatMap(tuple => tuple._2.replace("\r\nabc", "####abc").split("####")).collect()
```

And then loop the array to save the texts to output

```
for(str <- rdd){
  //saving codes here
}
```