# Reading CSV in Spark that has parent/child rows of different types

Tags: apache-spark, tree

I'll explain with the example below.

```
| Row No | Col0(Type) |      Col1    |  Col2        | Col3 |
|--------|------------|--------------|--------------|------|
| 1      | 01         |  data-c1-01  | $1600        |      |
| 2      | 01         |  data-c1-01  |   $12        |      |
| 3      | 02         |  data-c1-02  | 2019/11/30   |      |
| 4      | 03         |  data-c1-03  |   1.5        |      |
| 5      | 01         |  data-c1-01  |   $12        |      |
| 6      | 04         |  data-c1-04  |   *          |      |
```

Rows 1, 2 and 5 are the parent rows (type 01). Parent rows my have 0 or more child rows of different types. So row 2 has two child rows of type 02 and 03.

I need to load a reasonably large CSV in the above format and process parent rows with any of its child rows (which can vary in number). A child row, is any non 01 type row and its parent row is the first preceding 01 type row. So row order matters.

The only solution I can think of at the moment is to sequentially read and write line by line to introduce a unique key between each set of parent and child rows. Then load this new CSV to group by this key in spark.

Answer (score 0):

While I don’t think this is a very good case for Apache Spark, it is possible using Window functions to create a cumulative sum.

```py
In [1]: from pyspark.sql import Window
   ...: from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sum as sparksum, when
   ...: 
   ...: df = spark.createDataFrame(((1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 1), (6, 4)),
   ...:                            schema=("rowno", "type"))
   ...: wind = (Window
   ...:         .orderBy("rowno")
   ...:         .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
   ...:         )
   ...: (df
   ...:  .withColumn("group",
   ...:              sparksum(when(col("type") == 1, 1).otherwise(0)).over(wind))
   ...:  .show()
   ...:  )
   ...: 
   ...:  
19/12/01 01:38:19 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+-----+----+-----+                                                              
|rowno|type|group|
+-----+----+-----+
|    1|   1|    1|
|    2|   1|    2|
|    3|   2|    2|
|    4|   3|    2|
|    5|   1|    3|
|    6|   4|    3|
+-----+----+-----+
```

Note the warning there. It basically says that you loose all parallellism during this operation, so basically you’re reduced to single-core execution, which would be no different from sequentially going over the file with a single thread. Afterwards you can `repartition` again though.

Once you have the group number, you can run a `groupBy` (or `groupByKey`) and process the parent row with all of its child rows.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, I think the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48929086/1118067, is a bit better, assuming the files content remains in order.